# rspec not seeing database changes even though not in transaction mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have this in my spec_helper:

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

config.before(:suite) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
end

config.before(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  FactoryGirl.reload
end

config.before(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.start
end

config.after(:each) do
  Capybara.reset_sessions!
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

So basically no transactions should be used.

I have this callback in my Absence after_save:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(
%Q[insert into time_checks (user_id, date, minimal_hours)
select users.id, calendar.date, 0 from calendar
inner join users on users.id in (#{user_ids})
where not exists (select * from time_checks where time_checks.user_id = users.id and time_checks.date = calendar.date)
and calendar.date between '#{from}' and '#{to}'])
```

It's definitely hitting that code while doing the test.  When I try the SQL it inserts something in time_checks as well.

However when I do:

```
@absence = create(:absence, user: @user, from: "2015-09-10", to: "2015-09-10", hours: 3, category: 0)
Absence.count.should eq(1)
TimeCheck.count.should eq(1)
```

The last line is saying there are no records in time_checks.  Why would this be?

Comment: If you create an `Absence` from console, does `TimeCheck.count(:all)` increment by 1? Are you sure the output of the SQL in `after_save` is a valid `TimeCheck`?

Comment: Yes it worked in development and after_save was a valid TimeCheck however the calendar table was getting erased every time the tests ran.  See answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason.  The insert query is using a calendar table.  By running the tests, this table got truncated everytime which caused the insert not to insert anything.

The solution is to exclude the calendar table in the truncation like this:

```
excluded_tables = %w[calendar]

config.before(:suite) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation, {except: keep_tables})
end

config.before(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction, {except: keep_tables}
  FactoryGirl.reload
end
```